# Incorrect sizing in nicematrix when using iRow and jCol counters as exponent

Tags: nicematrix

I am trying to be fancy/lazy in `nicematrix` (version 5.19 on Overleaf TeX Live 2020) by generating a matrix using the `iRow` and `jCol` counters.

Here is an example of what I try to achieve :
[image: Ideal result]

The previous result is done with the following code :

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}%
    [
        r,
        first-row,
        last-col,
        code-for-first-row = \Block{}{\scriptstyle \color{blue} \arabic{jCol}},
        code-for-last-col = \scriptstyle \color{red} \arabic{iRow}
    ]
        & & & & \\
        (-1)^{1+1+1}(1+1) & (-1)^{1+2+1}(1+2) & (-1)^{1+3+1}(1+3) & (-1)^{1+3+1}(1+4) & \\
        (-1)^{2+1+1}(2+1) & (-1)^{2+2+1}(2+2) & (-1)^{2+3+1}(2+3) & (-1)^{2+3+1}(2+4) & \\
        (-1)^{3+1+1}(3+1) & (-1)^{3+2+1}(3+2) & (-1)^{3+3+1}(3+3) & (-1)^{3+3+1}(3+4) & \\
        (-1)^{4+1+1}(4+1) & (-1)^{4+2+1}(4+2) & (-1)^{4+3+1}(4+3) & (-1)^{4+3+1}(4+4) &
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

However, instead of defining each term on its own, I try to use `iRow` and `jCol` :

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}%
    [
        r,
        first-row,
        last-col,
        code-for-first-row = \Block{}{\scriptstyle \color{blue} \arabic{jCol}},
        code-for-last-col = \Block{}{\scriptstyle \color{red} \arabic{iRow}}
    ]
        & & & & \\
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) & \\
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) & \\
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) & \\
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) &
        (-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1}(\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol}) & \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

Which lead to the following result :
[image: Bad sizing]

There seems to be a sizing problem when using the counters, but the problem only seems to appear when using them as exponent, since removing it also bring back the delimiters to the right place :

```
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}%
    [
        r,
        first-row,
        last-col,
        code-for-first-row = \Block{}{\scriptstyle \color{blue} \arabic{jCol}},
        code-for-last-col = \Block{}{\scriptstyle \color{red} \arabic{iRow}}
    ]
        & & & & \\
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) & \\
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) & \\
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) & \\
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) &
        (\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + \arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol}) & \\
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation*}
```

leads to
[image: No exponent : correct sizing]

Finally, `nicematrix` offers the `AutoNiceMatrix` commands, and when using them the sizing is correct :

```
\begin{equation*}
     \bAutoNiceMatrix{4-4}{(-1)^{\arabic{iRow} + \arabic{jCol} + 1} (\arabic{iRow}+\arabic{jCol})}
\end{equation*}
```

leads to
[image: AutoNiceMatrix]

For this usecase, the `AutoNiceMatrix` would be an option, but it is not always possible to define one general term for the matrix.

Has anyone encountered this problem and could help me "generate" my matrices instead of writing them by hand?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get the expected result with `nicematrix` 2021/07/23 v5.19. And also with TeX Live 2020 and `nicematrix` 2021/03/23 v5.13

Comment: I think you should try to recompile after deletion of the `aux` file. In Overleaf: "View logs" (on the right of the PDF panel) and "Clear cache files" (red button). Sometimes, when modifying a document using `nicematrix`, the informations written on the `aux` files are out-of-date (because they were valid only for the previous version of the document).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting the `aux` file and recompiling, as suggested by F. Pantigny in a comment, indeed solved the problem.

Thanks a lot!